# GPG: Generating signatures for multiple files

Tags: gpg, yubikey

Is there any way to sign multiple files with GPG when the signing key is stored on a keycard? (Or more specifically in my case, a Yubikey).

Currently, I have a script where I loop over a number of files that I want to sign, e.g.:

```bsh
for pkg in html/packages/*.tar;
do
    gpg2 --detach-sign --armor -o $pkg.sig $pkg
done
```

This works, but as there is a pin-code on my keycard I'm being prompted to enter
my pin for each file which gets very tiresome after just a few files.

Is there any way to sign all files at once? Alternatively, is there some workaround for the signing process such that the pin-code can be cached between invocations?

Comment: It appears that what you want (`--sign` + `--multifile`) is not currently implemented, https://dev.gnupg.org/T4930.

Comment: Can you add a variable to your script (or pass it in at invocation) to hold the PIN and then pass to `gpg` in batch mode?

Comment: Modifying the script with a variable is fine, although passing the pin on the command-line is probably not advised, as it could be stored in the history file. I believe I could use `pinentry` to get the pin securely, but how would I tell `gpg` to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get the PIN into a variable your script can use, you can do something like:

```
for pkg in html/packages/*.tar;
do
  echo ${PIN} | gpg --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --detach-sign --armor -o $pkg.sig $pkg
done
```

From the `man` page:

```
--passphrase-fd n
       Read the passphrase from file descriptor n. Only the first line will be read
       from file descriptor n. If you use 0 for n, the passphrase will be read from
       STDIN. This can only be used if only one passphrase is supplied.

       Note that since Version 2.0 this passphrase is only used if the option --batch
       has also been given. Since Version 2.1 the --pinentry-mode also needs to be set
       to loopback.
```

For more details on the `passphrase-fd` (where `gpg` should expect to receive the passphrase from) option, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895122/how-to-use-gnupgs-passphrase-fd-argument is probably helpful